# Call the new Operator be called individually without assigning to a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, new-operator, self-invoking-function

I am new to JS and having a piece of JavaScript codes from a tutorial:

```
class TypeWriter{
      
      constructor(x,y){
           this.x = x;
           this.y = y;
           this.type();
   }
}

TypeWriter.prototype.type() = function(){......}
```

So far it's all good, but then I got confused by how the new operator is called:

```
function init(){
      const a,b;
      new TypeWriter(a,b);
}
```

The function works well and the type() method is invoked automatically, which makes me lost. What 's the reason behind it? Why the type() is invoked by just calling the new TypeWriter()?

In my understanding, the type() and the new operator should be like this:

```
const typeWriter = new TypeWriter(a,b);
typeWriter.type();
```

Can anyone explain how it works to me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `TypeWriter.prototype.type()` this is you calling the type function. Not assigning it. Also you're calling `this.type();` in your constructor. Which is automatically called when a class is constructed.

Comment: When you use `new` operator on the class, the code inside `constructor` will run and you have `this.type()` in the `constructor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate an object of a class using the `new` keyword, you are basically calling the constructor of that class. And all the code in the constructor will run.

So, this is how the constructor looks like:

```
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.type();
```

The two arguments that you pass to the constructor are added as properties of the object (x, y).
Now, in the third line you call the `type` method which is why the `type` method is being called immediately when you instantiate.

Also, there's a small error to how you're adding the `type` method to the prototype, you don't put parenthesis after `type`. (see the snippet below)

```js
class TypeWriter {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.type();
  }
}

TypeWriter.prototype.type = function() {
  console.log("Type method called");
}

const typeWriter = new TypeWriter(10, 20); // Method called once
typeWriter.type(); // Method called again
```

If you don't want to call the `type` method while instantiating you can simply remove its call from the constructor. (see the snippet below)

```js
class TypeWriter {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

TypeWriter.prototype.type = function() {
  console.log("Type method called");
}

const typeWriter = new TypeWriter(10, 20);
typeWriter.type(); // Method called once
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Such a detailed answer!

Comment: Answer accepted, but my reputation is too low to vote it up.

Comment: @Katrine.R No worries!